# How to use SFDX to import related records using an External ID from CSV File?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

My question is as the title stated.

In data loader, we can achieve this by explained in this official article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002783&type=1

One field in `object B` refers to an external Id in `object A`, by doing this `object B` is linking to `object A`.

In SFDX we can use `data:bulk:upsert` to upsert data from CSV file. But it seems no way to link two objects?

Answer (score 4):

They use the same Bulk API (Data Loader: when enabled). So, the steps you need are outlined in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_rel_field_header_row.htm). You reference the relationship in the header column.

For standard relationships, you can use the relationship name:

```
FirstName,LastName,ReportsTo.Email
```

For custom relationships, you can use the custom relationship name:

```
Name,Mother_Of_Child__r.External_ID__c
```

For polymorphic relationships, you specify the related data type (e.g. Lead, Contact):

```
Subject,Priority,Status,Lead:Who.Email,Owner.Id
```

Make sure you import parents first, and that they have a unique External ID before using this technique.